# Should you use multiple React UI libraries in the same project?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

What is the coding standard on the use of UI libraries? I have a project that mainly uses react-bootstrap but I'm considering using React Suite for future components. Is it a bad habit to mix different UI libraries?

Comment: Wether or not libraries work well together is entirely dependant on the libraries in question, so there's no way to really answer this "correctly". However, as a general rule most large UI libraries **do not** play well together.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use multiple libraries in single react js project. But sometimes it impacts conflicts on UI-Libraries default styling like font-size, font, font-color, etc. So it is preferred that use less UI libraries during creating react-app.

Comment: We should prefer less or single UI package to keep the project and responsive. This will improve code quality as well.